# How to call thickbox from tinymce contextmenu plugin?

Tags: jquery, tinymce, thickbox

***How to add item in contextmenu of tinymce. I need to open a thickbox from contextmenu selection of tinymce***

```
    var url = "upload.php?keepThis=true&TB_iframe=1&width=1000&height=400&model=true";
    tb_show("Edit Image", url);
```

**I can call thickbox with above codes. Where i need to recode in contextmenu plugin. Help me**

Comment: thickbox is a javascript library to open another page in a popup Refer this site for thickbox http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

Comment: don't know, but this thread may be helpfull: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=5836

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? for example when right-clicking where you would like to open up a contextmenu from which you can choose what

Comment: once i right click on image edit image option want to display on contextmenu and once i click edit image option. i like to open a popup using thickbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, in that case you need to load the contextmenu plugin (do this before you load your custom plugin!)

```
plugins: '...,contextmenu,....,customcontextmenu,...',
```

Here is the full sample code for an own contextmenu plugin. You need to have this code inside a file called 'editor_plugin.js' (and a file called 'editor_plugin_src.js') in a subdirectory named 'contextmenu' of the plugins directory.

```
(function() {

  tinymce.PluginManager.requireLangPack('customcontextmenu');

  tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.customcontextmenu', {

    init : function(ed, url) {
        ed.addCommand('custom_option', function() {
            // do what you want here!!!
        });

// we need the real contextmenu in order to make this work
if (ed && ed.plugins.contextmenu) {

        // contextmenu gets called - this is what we do
    ed.plugins.contextmenu.onContextMenu.add(function(th, m, e, col) {

        // remove all options from standard contextmenu
        m.removeAll();

        // only if selected node is an image do this
        if (typeof e !== "undefined" && e.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'img'){

            th._menu.add({
                title: 'Option 1',
                icon: 'option1',  // you might need to specify an image here
                cmd: 'custom_option' // call command custom_option
            });

            m.addSeparator();

                        // Second option
            //m.add({
            //  title: 'Option 2',
            //  icon: 'option2',
            //  cmd: 'custom_option2'
            //});
        }
                else {
                   // you might want to hinder the display of the contextmenu in all other cases
                   // or present other options....
                }
    });
    }
   });
},

  // Register plugin
  tinymce.PluginManager.add('customcontextmenu', tinymce.plugins.customcontextmenu);


})();
```

Make sure the brackets are set right (i had to copy/paste and delete parts of the code so there might brackets be missing).

Comment: Your codes Helps me to develop my concept in a bright way. Thank u @Thariama

Comment: glad to have been able to help